# How to set unicode emoji to the the title of a UIButton in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, uibutton

EDIT:
found a way to convert it with lots of conversion, but seems sloppy:

```
let myStr = "1f601"
let str = String(Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(myStr, radix: 16)!)!))
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
for _ in 1...2 {
    let emojiButton               = UIButton()
    emojiButton.backgroundColor   = UIColor.green
    emojiButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
    emojiButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "AppleColorEmoji", size: CGFloat(16.0))
    emojiButton.setTitle(str, for: .normal)

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(emojiButton)

}
```

This for some reason gives two different symbols rather than the expected emoji, here's the result:

[image]

So now I'm confused as to why the %C format isn't showing unicode, and also why it's showing two different characters.

Comment: please add your "Edit:" as an Answer instead!

Answer (score 2):

```
let myStr = "\u{1f601}"
```

Is probably the easiest way to specify Unicode points in Swift.

Comment: yeah that works, but can't use string interpolation to iterate through a list of those values :/

Comment: You could just have an array and iterate through the array.  For instance: let myemotes = ["\u{1f601}", "\u{1f602}", ""]
for e in myemotes {
    print ("\(e)")
}